# How do I append on top of the body instead of the bottom?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to append this html:

`cover = soup.new_tag('div', id='cover', attrs={"style": 'position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0; left: 0; background: #fff; z-index:9999;'})`

right after the body tag, but when I use  `soup.html.append(cover)` it appends it to the bottom

Answer (score 3):

The `Tag.append(content)` function searches through the parse tree to find the `Tag` and append the `content` after the last element. If you want your `div` to be contained inside the `body`, you should at least use `body.append()` instead of `html.append()` but as you understood it will be the last element of the `body`.
So I would suggest you use the `insert_before()` function to insert the `cover` right before the first element of the `body`.

So, with this HTML sample code :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   The Dormouse's story
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="title">
   <b>
    The Dormouse's story
   </b>
  </p>
  <p class="story">
   ...
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can use `soup.p.insert_before(cover)` and it will insert the `div` as the first element of your `body` !

You can check the [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=append#insert-before-and-insert-after) documentation for more details :)